# How to disable mod_security for a subdomain?

Tags: mod-security

I'm trying to disable mod_security for a custom subdomain.

I tried to include the following in modsec/modsec2.user.conf.

SecRule SERVER_NAME "desktop.xyz.com" phase:1,nolog,allow,ctl:ruleEngine=off

But i'm getting "Syntax error on line 15 of /etc/apache2/conf.d/modsec/modsec2.user.conf:
ModSecurity: No action id present within the rule"